# Unset inherited face attribute

Tags: faces

Suppose I want the face `helm-match` to have an unset foreground. Unfortunately, `helm-match` inherits from `match` so, if I try to unset the foreground normally:

```el
(set-face-foreground 'helm-match nil)
```

The inherited foreground becomes active. I'd rather not mess with the `match` face itself (because I can't tell what ramifications that would have), and I would like to avoid hard coding the other values in `helm-match` because I use multiple themes.

How can I achieve this sanely?

Comment: *Just customize the face* (`helm-match`). That's what face customization is for. Show all the attributes in Customize, and uncheck the inheritance.

Comment: @Drew I would like to preserve the inheritance of other attributes.

Comment: So leave `Inherit` checked and check whatever other attributes you want to override any from the inherited face. The point is to use Customize (`customize-face`).

Answer (score 0):

Use `unspecified` as value instead.

See also [face attributes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Attributes.html).

Comment: Nope. `unspecified` causes the face to inherit the property from the parent.

Comment: @PythonNut: yes, from linked page: "An unspecified attribute tells Emacs to refer instead to a parent face", what would you want instead?

Comment: What about `unspecified` for the `inherit` attribute?

Comment: @npostavs I would like the face attribute to be truly unspecified. That is, left to lower priority faces on the same character, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to see how your own Emacs version handles the situation. let's for instance consider changing the `Info-quoted` face:

1. Do `M-x customize-face` press enter, and then type `Info-quoted` and press enter (note that the I should be capital) to see the attributes.
2. Do the changes you want. In this case, let the checkmark for "Inherit" be there but delete the value (e.g use the "Del" button)
3. Press "Apply" button. At this stage you can see the face change applied to all buffers.
4. Press the "state" button to open the menu
5. From the menu, click on "Show lisp expression"
6. Copy the lisp expression and use it in your Emacs config

[image: screenshot of first three steps]

[image: screenshot of steps 4 and 5]

[image: screenshot of step 6]