# What is the correct way to unset :foreground color?

Tags: faces, colors

For better experience [color-identifiers-mode](https://github.com/ankurdave/color-identifiers-mode/) recommends turning off colors for everything. The example in README does it by setting `:foreground` of faces to `nil`, which kinda works.

However doing it globally is unwanted for unsupported modes, e.g. for Markdown. So faces have to be set locally, which is the problem: setting `:foreground` to `nil` triggers an error:

```
(face-remap-add-relative 'font-lock-keyword-face '((:foreground nil)))
[*Messages* buffer ↓]
Invalid face attribute :foreground nil
Invalid face reference: font-lock-keyword-face
```

[Setting to 'unspecified](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19947/unset-inherited-face-attribute) triggers:

```
(face-remap-add-relative 'font-lock-keyword-face '((:foreground 'unspecified)))
[*Messages* buffer ↓]
Invalid face attribute :foreground (quote unspecified)
Invalid face reference: font-lock-keyword-face
```

Using `unspecified` without `'` changes nothing.

And, finally, using an empty string does work, but triggers a warning:

```
(face-remap-add-relative 'font-lock-keyword-face '((:foreground "")))
[*Messages* buffer ↓]
Unable to load color ""
```

I personally could settle down with an empty string, but I'm going to change the README recommendation about setting faces, and triggering warnings for users not a good user experience.

So, what is the correct way of unsetting the `:foreground` color?

Comment: I have been admonished by experienced Emacs users that the manual recommends using `face-remap-add-relative`, so that is what I have tried to use in some of my on-line answers.  However, in my own setup I set the `face-remapping-alist` directly as either global with `setq-default` or local with `setq-local`.  It is something you may wish to consider, even though people will tell that the manual recommends using `face-remap-add-relative`.  I change my modeline background this way, and also the faces in the minibuffer depending upon whether my cursor is in the minibuffer when open or elsewhere.

Comment: @lawlist ok, given nobody answered, I decided to give it a try. If I understand correctly, you were meaning that manually setting `:foreground` to `nil` should work. Unfortunately it doesn't. Minimal steps are: *1)* split Emacs window to buffers \*Messages\* and a C++ with a function declaration *2)* in C++ buffer execute *M-:* `(add-to-list 'face-remapping-alist (cons 'font-lock-function-name-face '((:foreground nil))))`. *3)* move around a little, and see how \*Messages\* got spammed with errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`nil` is not a valid attribute value for `:foreground`, which can be a string or `unspecified`<sup>*</sup>, see [(elisp) Face Attributes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Attributes.html):

```
   Apart from the values given below, each face attribute can have the
value `unspecified'. [...]

`:foreground'
     Foreground color, a string.  The value can be a system-defined
     color name, or a hexadecimal color specification.  *Note Color
     Names::.  On black-and-white displays, certain shades of gray are
     implemented by stipple p9atterns.
```

I think the only options are to inherit from the `default` face (which overrides also non-colour attributes), or set the foreground to the default's face current one (which means it won't update if you change the default face colour):

```el
(face-remap-add-relative 'font-lock-keyword-face '(:inherit default))
(face-remap-add-relative 'font-lock-keyword-face `(:foreground ,(face-foreground 'default)))
```

---

<sup>*</sup> Your attempt to use `unspecified` caused errors because you had an extra `quote`, but even fixing that, it will only tell Emacs to take the foreground from the non-remapped face, i.e., do absolutely nothing.

Answer (score -1):

`C-h f face-remap-add-relative` tells you:

> `face-remap-add-relative` is an autoloaded compiled Lisp function in
>   `face-remap.el`.
>
> `(face-remap-add-relative FACE` **`&rest`** `SPECS)`
>
> Add a face remapping entry of `FACE` to `SPECS` in the current buffer.
>   Return a cookie which can be used to delete this remapping with
>   `face-remap-remove-relative`.
>
> The remaining arguments, `SPECS`, should form a list of faces.
>   Each list element should be either a face name or a property list
>   of face attribute/value pairs.  If more than one face is listed,
>   that specifies an aggregate face, in the same way as in a `face'
>   text property, except for possible priority changes noted below.
>
> The face remapping specified by `SPECS` takes effect alongside the
>   remappings from other calls to `face-remap-add-relative` for the
>   same `FACE`, as well as the normal definition of `FACE` (at lowest
>   priority).  This function tries to sort multiple remappings for
>   the same face, so that remappings specifying relative face
>   attributes are applied after remappings specifying absolute face
>   attributes.
>
> The base (lowest priority) remapping may be set to something
>   other than the normal definition of `FACE` via `face-remap-set-base`.

---

The `&rest` in the lambda list tells you that the `SPECS` are not passed as a single list argument but are instead passed as individual args.

Try this:

```el
(face-remap-add-relative 'font-lock-keyword-face '(:foreground nil))
```

not this:

```el
(face-remap-add-relative 'font-lock-keyword-face '((:foreground nil)))
```

That will pass `((:foreground nil))` as argument `SPECS` to the function.

Comment: It behaves the same as with double parentheses. For the record, I don't know why the double parentheses, but it's [the way from the answer here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7281/how-to-modify-face-for-a-specific-buffer). Anyway, the syntax is definitely not a problem because if you replace `nil` with a color, e.g. `"blue"`, it works just fine.